# ESC/POS Epson TM-T20 Status with PHP

Tags: php, status, epson

I have a Epson TM-T20 (only Ethernet Interface) and I need some Help to get a Status of the Printer via PHP.
For Printing I use this [Script](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php).
For getting the Status I tried the following Code:

```
<?php

$fp = fsockopen ('10.1.10.2, 9100');     //Open a Connection
frwrite($fp, chr(16).chr(4).chr(4));     //POS Command "DLE EOT n" Status Transmission
$stat = fgets($fp);                      //Get the Status
fclose($fp);                             //Close Connection
$bit = ord($stat);                       //Get Integer
echo $bit;                               //A this Point I get only "0"

?>
```

I use a Windows 7 System with XAMPP as a lab environment.

Thanks for your Help.

P.S.: Sorry for my Language but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: have you find the solution at this question? also i need it :)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're using [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)() without any arguments, which will block until an entire line is read.

Most ESC/POS communication doesn't involve line feeds, and I think this command only returns one character, so I would suggest trying:

```
$stat = fgets($fp, 2);
```

Which should return the one-character status string.